# Is there a way to use python strings as html code?

Tags: python, html

I'm kind of new to HTML code, I would like to show some images that my Python code has selected and this is what I came up with. 
application.py

```
s = f"""
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='{file1}')}}" />
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='{file2}')}}" />
    """
    return render_template("index.html", s = s)
```

file1 and file2 being jpg image file names

index.html

```
<p>
   {{ s|e }}
</p>
```

This code is just writing the html tags that I made, not displaying an image. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Would you not need to quote the filename parameter, e.g. `filename='%s'`? What is `url_for`? What web framework are you using? Edit the question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: sounds like a task for [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/)

Comment: Made some edits to the code in the question, still no luck. Any ideas?